# remove view and add another view

Tags: ios, uiview

i have two view in my ViewController that i control view has i show with a button. When user click at button1, it hide viewA and show viewB and when user click at button2 it hide viewB and show viewA. But after i remove the viewA with removeFromSuperView, when i click to add again it not show.

What happen ?

```
- (IBAction)btnViewB:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"remove viewA");
     [viewA removeFromSuperview];
     [self.view addSubview:viewB];
}
- (IBAction)btnViewA:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"remove viewB");
     [viewB removeFromSuperview];
     [self.view addSubview:viewA];
}
```

> I solved this problem, but i want to know why if i use removeFromSuperView it not works

```
- (IBAction)btnViewB:(id)sender {
    viewA.hidden = YES;
    viewB.hidden = NO;
}
- (IBAction)btnViewA:(id)sender {
    viewA.hidden = NO;
    viewB.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have class pointers to those views? I can probably think that they are not being preserved.

Comment: I'm using IB and created a Outlet for this view! I need to create the view again using frame ?

Comment: No, he's saying that you're probably not releasing the view itself because the view still has pointers to it.